# How to handle no data between ASP.net web api and angular JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json

We have a web app which uses ASP.net web API in the backend and angular JS in the front end,looking for some suggestions on if the backend can send a JSON object with null values to angular JS(like in Option#1) and angular JS can parse it or in the cases where the keyvalues are null should the backend parse it and send as in #2?either ways is it a big deal?what are the pros and cons of each option?

```
Option#1
    data:
    { "name":null, "age":null, "car":null }
Option#2    
    data:[] data:null
```

Comment: I am fairly sure these types of questions are not for stack overflow.  But given your examples you should return option 2 if there is not related record in the database and return option 1 if there is an object in the database but no associated data with that object.

Comment: what exactly you mean by object in the database?

Comment: Basically option one tells me you have a record in the database with no values in the fields.  Option two tells me you don't have a record in the database.

Comment: how can a record exist in database with no values?can you please suggest an example?

Comment: You can add an object to a database without any values except for primary keys or required properties.  Example if I have a DateTime? I can add a record with the DateTime? field as null.

Comment: David - even in that case..whats the justification to send null values even if the record exists?angular has to parse the null values object and hide the corresonding grid...

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is your use case, but if I was calling your API and saw those two results back that is what I would assume the data is telling me.